# Bringing an app from background to foreground automatically when an UILocalNotification fires?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

As I understand in iOS, when an UILocalNotification fires, an alert window would pop up and ask the user to open that app.

I want to show that app to the user directly when an UILocalNotification fires, no user intervention is required.

Is it possible to bring that app from background to foreground automatically when an UILocalNotification fires?

Thank you.

Comment: I doubt Apple would let you do this, this is taking control from the user, and forcing them to use your app. The only way i know is to present a button on the notification which will launch your app.

Comment: I understand that there is a limitation. However, my app is an alarm clock app, I want to switch to the alarm clock app directly when an alarm triggers.

Comment: Yes, i understand, but its a limitation of the OS. I'm fairly certain that there is no way to tell the OS to automatically switch to your app without presenting some sort of choice to the user. The best thing to do would be to present a notification to the user offering to stop the ringing or go to the app or whatever is best suited for your needs.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation. Perhaps I need to find some kinds of workarounds.

Answer (score 2):

This currently isn't possible using allowed public APIs on stock iOS devices.

Answer (score 2):

The main logic Apple's restrictions is to protect both the user and the device(its memory, battery etc..) from harmful applications. And the logic of iOS notifications is that they let the operating system user intervention. As @hotpaw2 has said, there is no way to do that in public API's, which means if you do that your app will be rejected..

**NOTE***:* If you target jailbreak devices it is possible, i can help a little too if you want that